# HTML chart display issue - move the chart inside of the card

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I used the "Range Selector plugin" to create a line chart with the date selector.

The following codes are in my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/rangeSelector.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="selectordiv"></div>

 <div class="card shadow mb-4">
   <div class="card-header py-3">
     <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Area Chart</h6>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-line">
     <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<script> var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

var data = [];
var visits = 10;
for (var i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
  visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({ date: new Date(2018, 0, i), value: visits });
}

chart.data = data;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 5;

dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.groupCount = 500;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

var selector = new am4plugins_rangeSelector.DateAxisRangeSelector();
selector.container = document.getElementById("selectordiv");
selector.axis = dateAxis;
                        
</script>                       
      </div>
         </div>
           </div>
```

But my chart doesn't display properly. It is outside of the card:
[image: My chart is outside of the card area]

Please advise what I should adjust to move the chart inside of the card

Comment: Your javascript code is referencing `chartdiv` but I don't see that in your HTML. Maybe that just needs to be updated to the proper card element?

Comment: I added them in my post just now. Please advise how should I adjust it to the card element. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your #chartdiv element inside the area chart card body.  I have tried to do this with the HTML you supplied but it seems to be missing some CSS.  I've managed to get it working though:

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

var data = [];
var visits = 10;
for (var i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
  visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({
    date: new Date(2018, 0, i),
    value: visits
  });
}

chart.data = data;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 5;

dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.groupCount = 500;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

var selector = new am4plugins_rangeSelector.DateAxisRangeSelector();
selector.container = document.getElementById("selectordiv");
selector.axis = dateAxis;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="selectordiv"></div>
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Area Chart</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-line">
      <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/rangeSelector.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works! You are so amazing. Thank you so much!!